# Coldfusion looping over query and display html tag only one time

Tags: sql, loops, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I have  a problem with looping over sql queries and if the query is not null then i must display some html tag. The problem is that let's say that query find 3 items, it will display 3x file instead of 1x.

Here is my code:

```
<cfquery name="client_id" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    Select borrower_id,client_id,id from contracts where borrower_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#trim(url.ID)#">
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="client_id">
    <cfquery name="Payment_log" datasource="#application.dsn#">
        SELECT *
        FROM paymentLog
        WHERE contract_id = <cfqueryparam value="#client_id.id#" maxlength="36" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT">
            AND DateDelete IS NULL
        ORDER BY date_log, id
    </cfquery>

    <cfloop query="Payment_log">

        <cfquery name="payment_log_file" datasource="#application.dsn#">
            SELECT file_name
            FROM paymentLog_file
            WHERE log_id = #Payment_log.id#
        </cfquery>

        <cfloop query="payment_log_file">

            <cfif payment_log_file.recordCount neq 0>
                <th>file name</th>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

This is the result

```
<th>file name</th>
<th>file name</th>
<th>file name</th>
```

This is what i want/need

```
<th>file name</th>
```

Okay so I changed my sql query as suggested by Matt Busche and Dan Bracuk to this:

```
SELECT plf.log_id
FROM paymentLog pl
        LEFT JOIN paymentLog_file plf ON pl.id = plf.log_id
WHERE contract_id = <cfqueryparam value="#client_id.id#" maxlength="36" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT">
        AND DateDelete IS NULL
ORDER BY plf.log_id, date_log, id
```

And I get this:
[image: SQL Result]

This is what i get
[image: Current situation]

This is what i want/need
[image: This is what i need/want]

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  In plain english, what information are you trying to display? Example "I want to display the most recent payment information X for Y". Also, please post a sample of the data in the various tables and the expected result.

Comment: Try using an inner join instead of a left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to try to go farther than I did and reduce this to one query overall if possible, but this should get you on the right track

Combine your two inner queries into one query, add an order by attribute on the duplicate row type, and then add a `group` by attribute to your `cfloop`. If you're on CF10? or lower you may need to use `cfoutput` instead of `cfloop` to use the `group` attribute

```
<cfquery name="client_id" datasource="#application.dsn#">
 Select borrower_id,client_id,id from contracts where borrower_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#trim(url.ID)#">
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="client_id">
  <cfquery name="Payment_log" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT pl.log_id log_id
    FROM paymentLog pl
        INNER JOIN paymentLog_file plf ON pl.log_id = plf.log_id
    WHERE contract_id = <cfqueryparam value="#client_id.id#" maxlength="36" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_BIGINT">
        AND DateDelete IS NULL
    ORDER BY pl.log_id, date_log, id
 </cfquery>

  <cfloop query="Payment_log" group="log_id">
    <th>file name</th>
  </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I tried your method of joining tabels and then grouping by log_id, but it gives me same result as before(3x <th>file name</th>). I want to display <th>file name</th> only 1 time, no matter how many results it gives me from query. Then i am displaying all of these 3 results in <td>

Comment: Is your query ordered by the group by column? Dump your query to the screen and look at the results. You also need an order by on your first query.

Comment: Matt - Why not convert everything to joins, instead of the less efficient querying within a loop?

Comment: @Leigh 100% agree. With a small database, you may not notice the impact of calling the database for every iteration of your outer query. But when I worked with larger databases that only had a few million rows in some of the tables, it was very obvious to see the impact. Instead of looping over a query to build other queries, my vote would be for one query with all of the needed data and then loop over that query's results to extract what you need. Your DBA will thank you.

Comment: @Leigh Feel free to edit the answer, but this is listed at the beginning of the answer "You'll want to try to go farther than I did and reduce this to one query overall if possible, but this should get you on the right track"

Comment: @Shawn - Definitely, and not just with huge tables . I worked with an old app that did something similar. As the data and number of users started to increase, performance *really* tanked until we rewrote the sql.

Comment: @MattBusche - Nah, it was a gentle hint for *you* to improve it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very long comment.  Posting it as an answer enables me to make it readable.

First, running a query inside a loop of another query is rarely a good idea.  The code in your question suggests that your SQL knowledge needs work.  Why not a single query that selects from both tables?  If you don't know how to do that, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Second, you say you only want to display one record out of three.  Which one?  If you don't know, ask the person who wants this done.  This comes under the general category of learning what the code is supposed to accomplish before you start writing it.

Comment: Indeed i need to work on my SQL knowledge.
And for the second, I need to show <th>file name</th> only 1 time, and then in <td> i am showing all of the 3 results in the table

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to return 1 file, just say so in the query.

```
<cfquery name="payment_log_file" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT TOP 1 file_name
    FROM paymentLog_file
    WHERE log_id = #Payment_log.id#
</cfquery>
```

If you want to display MULTIPLE files inside that HTML tag, just wrap the loop inside it.

Comment: These will give me only 1 result from this query, but I will still have 3x <th>file name</th>.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend combining the whole query into one dataset, then working with that to build your output.

```
SELECT c.borrower_id,c.client_id,c.id AS contracts_id
    , pl.* /* But don't use *. Explicitly call only column names that you need. */
    , plf.[file_name] /* Brackets because "file_name" is a built-in SQL function. */
FROM  contracts c 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN paymentLog pl ON c.id = pl.contract_id   
            AND pl.DateDelete IS NULL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN paymentLog_file plf ON plf.log_id = pl.id
WHERE c.borrower_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#trim(url.ID)#">
ORDER BY pl.log_id, pl.date_log, pl.id /* Is this last ORDER BY needed? Which id are you wanting to sort on? Make sure it's in the SELECT. */
```

This will also let you dump out your entire dataset in one batch so that you can see what you're actually working with. From here you should be able to get it to output what you are looking for.

And I would also validate your url.ID before you pass it to your cfqueryparam.

Comment: He needs to use INNER JOIN's so he doesn't get blank rows

Comment: It depends on what data he wants to return. If he wants to exclude contracts that have no payments, then yes, INNER JOIN. But if he needs contracts that have no payments also, LEFT OUTER JOIN.